# Set Button Text On Create not set text as define

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a code to change text as on create

```
  public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button btnbut = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnbut);
            TextView txtvw = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtView);
            txtvw.Text = "Hello World";
            btnbut.Text = "Hello WOrld";
        }
    }
```

#### My main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1.0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnbut" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run and open app with emulator the Text has remain the same as define on main.axml not the text define `OnCreate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and should result in:

[image]

Try performing a **clean all/build all** on your solution and retry your app on the emulator again.

Note: If it is still not updating the app on the emulator correctly:

Within the emulator:

```
Setting / Apps / Select your app / *Uninstall*
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover

Comment: @TouchyVivace no problem, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

i think i got your i dont use xamrain but i think this is the error try changing

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

to

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.My main);
```

coz your layout name is "My main" not "main"

Comment: :) yes you are absolutely right seeraj brother  but as i said i dont use xamrain so i dont know either they acceptable in xamrain. If its the case of  native then you cant even build your project with such naming convention